# Point subdomain to wordpress path

Tags: mod-rewrite, wordpress

I have a single Wordpress instance hosted at 1.2.3.4 with the following DNS settings:

```
A foo.com 1.2.3.4
A category.foo.com 1.2.3.4
```

The site is accessible from both hostnames, however, I would like requests to `category.foo.com` to render the content at `foo.com/category`.

In a working scenario, the following requests would be functional:

```
category.foo.com -> foo.com/category
category.foo.com/abc -> foo.com/category/abc
```

I'm currently trying to solve this by using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^category.foo.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) /category$ [L]
```

However, this results in an infinite loop as each request is always rewritten. I've also tried using the `[NS]` flag with the `RewriteRule` thinking that that would stop the redirect on subsequent requests but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there something I'm missing with regards to `mod_rewrite` or is there a different approach I should go with?

Note that I do not want `category.foo.com` to 301 redirect to `foo.com` so visitors arriving at `category.foo.com` should see that in their browser.

Comment: You are rewriting category.foo.com to category.foo.com/category which gets rewritten again to category.foo.com/category etc. So you need to learn how those rewrite rules work, like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Answer (score 0):

Configure a virtual host for each domain. You can configure all virtual hosts in the main config file or place each in a separate file inside of the sites-enabled directory. Examples can be found [here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) Yours could look somthing like this.

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress/category"
    ServerName category.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```